# Check if a specific Attributes exist in an Element

Tags: c#, xml

i need to check if a specific Attributes `ConnectionInd` exists in the Element of `FlightSegment`.
If it exist, i will store the value, if it doesnt, i will move on and read the next attributes.

The following is if it exist:

```
<FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="06-16T06:10" ConnectionInd="O" DepartureDateTime="2013-06-16T00:15" SmokingAllowed="false" eTicket="true">
     <Destination ... />
</FlightSegment>
```

And this is if it doesn't exist:

```
<FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="03-27T17:35" DepartureDateTime="2013-03-27T13:30" SmokingAllowed="false" eTicket="true">
     <Destination ... />
</FlightSegment>
```

i'm checking it with the following code but when there's no `ConnectionInd`, it will throw an error saying `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

```
if (FlightSegment.Item(f).Attributes["ConnectionInd"].Value != "" && FlightSegment.Item(f).Attributes["ConnectionInd"] != null)
{
    string conInd = FlightSegment.Item(f).Attributes["ConnectionInd"].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vice versa:

First check

```
FlightSegment.Item(f).Attributes["ConnectionInd"] != null
```

then

```
FlightSegment.Item(f).Attributes["ConnectionInd"].Value != ""
```

Otherwise if it's indeed null, you will get NullReferenceException which you're actually getting.

---

More efficient:

```
var att = FlightSegment.Item(f).Attributes["ConnectionInd"];
if (var != null)
{
    string cind = att.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be a method like hasAttribute or something like that that you should use instead of *FlightSegment.Item(f).Attributes["ConnectionInd"].Value* because if the "ConnectionInd" does not exist you are trying to get "Value" out of a null object and that will cause an exception.